# Removing widgets from QGridLayout by removing the layout frame

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have added frame to a grid layout along with two labels (The two labels lie inside the frame). What I am trying to achieve is to remove the frame and two labels by removing the frame alone (since the labels lie inside the frame). Currently I have to remove all the three separately.

```
def somefunc():
       
    mainhbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    firstgrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout() 
    secondgrid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()

    bgframe = QFrame()
    bgframe.setStyleSheet("background-color:white")

    toplabel = QLabel('Top Label')
    bottomlabel = QLabel('Bottom Label')

    firstgrid.addWidget(toplabel)
    firstgrid.addWidget(bottomlabel)

    bgframe.setLayout(firstgrid)
    secondgrid.addWidget(bgframe)
    mainhbox.addlayout(secondgrid)
```

Now, what I expect to happen :

`bgframe.hide()` should remove the frame as well as the embedded labels in it. But, this is only removing the frame.

How I am doing it currently:

```
toplabel.hide()
bottomlabel.hide()
bgframe.hide()
```

Comment: From your code snippet, it doesn't look like the labels are inside the frame? `grid1` doesn't interact with `bgframe` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Please edit your post to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as right now your code doesn't match what you're explaining. Also, be more careful when [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) and ensure that it's displayed correctly in the post preview.

Comment: Why are you trying to add `bgframe` to its own layout?

Comment: @abarry,@ekhumoro..... I have edited the code. Is it making sense now?

Comment: @UjjwalMohanty The only issue I can see is that `mainhbox.addlayout(secondgrid)` should be `mainhbox.addWidget(bgframe)`.